# How to create custom checkstyle tool?

Tags: java, jar, checkstyle

I am writing custom checkstyle rules to run it on my target project. I have created one project which holds the custom checkstyle rules. To run the custom checkstyle, I am using the following command `java -classpath myCustomCheck.jar;checkstyle-5.6-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c config.xml myFile.java`.

In place of `myFile.java`, if I give my target project folder it is not working as it expects a Java file as argument.

I want to run my myCustomCheck.jar on my target project. However, I don't want this jar to be included in my target project. I don't want to include it as a plugin either. I want to create it as an external tool from where I want to run this on my target project.

For that I thought of creating a new Java project and then running this command `java -classpath myCustomCheck.jar;checkstyle-5.6-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c config.xml myFile.java` from that project. Then I have to create this new project as a jar and run it.

However, I don't think it is a correct way. I want to run this checkstyle in a single click. The target project could be at any location on the PC. Any idea on how this can be done would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to do it.

I would suggest to create your own launcher which will take path to your target folder as an input.

This launcher will internally fetch all java files from that target folder, and apply checkstyle for each using the specified jar.

You may use windows batch file or linux shell script to execute this one line command for one click implementation.

Other way is to only use windows batch file/linux shell script to call checkstyle, Here you would need to process the things in bat file. Take an input of target folder, fetch all java files, and process them using checkstyle.

Hope it would give you some directions.

Comment: Hi Hemant. Thanks for the suggestion. This is a very straightforward and easy approach. But In this case I have to place ```checkstyle-5.6-all.jar```, ```myCustomCheck.jar```, ```custom_check.xml```  and the bat file itself in one folder to execute the command. That's a lot of file to distribute even with zipping the folder. But what I wanted to do is, wrapping them all into one project and distribute the jar of the project and let the users select the target project folder. I wanted to minimise it as much as possible for my fellow programmers.

Comment: Even if you wrap in one project these files, anyway you would need to distribute(though in form of a single jar containing all these) in order to achieve task.